# In RSA, rationale for prime $p$ with $p-1$ having prime factor $u$ with $u-1$ having large prime factor?

Tags: rsa, prime-numbers

In the [1978 RSA paper](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/Rsapaper.pdf), it is recommended, among other things, to choose primes $p$ such that $(p-1)$ has a large prime factor $u$. This was motivated by [Pollard's p-1 algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_p_%E2%88%92_1_algorithm). Further, the authors state:

> Additional security is provided by ensuring that $(u−1)$ also has a large prime factor.

What was the motivation for that?

Comment: It should be noted that [elliptic curve factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_prime#Application_of_strong_primes_in_cryptography) has made this security requirement redundant. On the other hand, ensuring `(p - 1)` has a large prime factor requires very little extra effort.

Comment: @Brett Hale: I think you mean that ECC has made redundant the requirement _to choose primes $p$ such that $(p−1)$ has a large prime factor $u$_. The question is about a different second requirement. Also, ECC may _not_ obsolete the first requirement in some cases: more than 2 primes, and enormously many public moduli, with the adversary content factoring a single one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue, and its history, was discussed at length in [Silverman and Rivest](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/RivestSilverman-AreStrongPrimesNeededForRSA.pdf). The relevant passage here is in Section 6, which I quote:

> In 1977 Simmons and Norris [53] discussed the following "cycling" or
>   "superencryption" attack on the RSA cryptosystem: given a ciphertext
>   C, consider decrypting it by repeatedly encrypting it with the same
>   public key used to produce it in the first place, until the message
>   appears. Thus, one looks for a fixed point of the transformation of
>   the plaintext under modular exponentiation. Since the encryption
>   operation effects a permutation of $\mathbb{Z}_n =  \{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$, the message can eventually be obtained in this
>   manner. Rivest [46] responds to their concern by (a) showing that the
>   odds of success are minuscule if the n is the product of two
>   $p^{--}$-strong primes, and (b) arguing that this attack is really a
>   factoring algorithm in disguise, and should be compared with other
>   factoring attacks.

Comment: Thanks. I located Rivest [46] [here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/pubs/Riv78a.pdf). Will try to understand the reasoning justifying that the requirement makes cycling attacks harder.