# In RSA, how to make sure that $p-1$ and $q-1$ are still hard to factorize?

Tags: rsa, factoring

See [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2303/in-rsa-rationale-for-prime-p-with-p-1-having-prime-factor-u-with-u-1-ha). The comment by Brett Hale stated:

> On the other hand, ensuring $(p - 1)$ has a large prime factor requires very little extra effort.

What's actually the 'little extra effort'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The procedure to do this is:

- Find a large prime factor $r$
- When searching for the prime $p$, look among numbers of the form $rk+1$

When we find our prime $p$, we know that $p-1$ will have $r$ as a factor.

Step 1 is comparatively cheap compared to original search from the prime $p$; we select an $r$ which is large (as far as factors of $p-1$ go), but is small compared to $p$.

Step 2 is the original prime search, with an additional condition.  That additional condition doesn't actually slow it down; it doesn't make checking a candidate any more expensive, nor does it make it less likely that a candidate is actually prime.

Hence, the has little extra effort; step 1 is fairly cheap, and step 2 has no additional cost.

Comment: IME step 2 is more expensive in the sense that it is less likely, given a fixed prime $r$ and a randomly selected $k$ of a fixed size, a number of the form $rk + 1$ is a prime, compared to a completely random odd integer of the same size. I only have experimental evidence to support this conjecture, though.

Comment: @HenrickHellström: that sounds unlikely.  We know that asymptotically, for fixed $r$, $i$ relatively prime, the probability that $p = rk+i$ is prime (as $k$ goes to infinity) is $r / (\phi(r) \log p) \approx 1 /\log p$.  In other words, the $i=1$ case is no less likely to yield a prime than any other value of $i$.  Now, this is an asymptotic result, it's possible that something odd happens for the moderate values of $k$ we use; I just find that unlikely.

Comment: @Poncho: Well, our results show that finding primes $p$ with $p-1$ having large prime factors might take about 10 times longer. Another possibility is that Rabin-Miller is more likely to return false positive in the first iterations for $p = rk + 1$, which would also cause a slow down.

Comment: @HenrickHellström: Hmmmm, that's not my experience.  It's been a few years, but I did try RSA key generation with and without "subprimes" (X9.31); my conclusion was that the 100 bit subprimes didn't slow down the key generation much at all.  As for Miller Rabin, well, the cases where it is likely to return a false positive is if $\phi(n)/(n-1)$ was a simple rational number; making sure $n-1$ had a particular factor isn't likely to cause that.

Comment: @Poncho: If you look closely at FIPS 186 prime generation, it contains a counter that makes the search for $p$ break and generate a new $q$. If you don't have that step, you might end up with a subprime for which finding a prime is infeasible.

Comment: Ah, no, I was comparing apples to oranges: The algorithms I was timing were too different to make sense of comparing them.