# Key space vs Cardinality of 1024-bit RSA

Tags: rsa, public-key, keys

I have been trying to figure out the encryption key space, and cardinality of 1024-bit RSA. From my understanding, the key generated from 1024-bit will be primes greater than $2^{1023}$ but less than $2^{1024}$. So, there are approximately $8\times10^{307}$ types of keys that can be used.

Is this the key space or the cardinality, and how do you distinguish the two from RSA ?

Comment: Actually, for 1024-bit RSA, the primes generated will typically be 512 bits each...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Definitions

In RSA, an *encryption key* is a pair of integers $(N,e)$ with $N$ the product of $m\ge2$ distinct odds secret primes $r_i$ (with $0<i\le m$), and $e$ is such that $\gcd(e,\lambda(N))=1$ where $\lambda(N)=\operatorname{lcm}(r_1-1,\dots,r_m-1)$ is the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function). It follows that $e$ is odd. Typically, other conditions are added, like $e\ge 3$ (because $e=1$ gives no security), or that each of the $r_i$ is large for some definition of that (because small $r_i$ can be easily found from $N$, and then are no longer secret). Other conditions are commonly added, and discussed later in this answer.

The most natural definition of *encryption key space* is the set of pairs $(N,e)$ matching the applicable conditions defined in a particular variant of RSA. The *cardinality of the encryption key space* is the number of elements in that set if it is finite, else the cardinality is $\aleph_0$ (the cardinality of $\mathbb N$ and all [countable sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set)).

Strictly speaking, by the definition above, the cardinality of the encryption key space of 1024-bit RSA is $\aleph_0$, because we put no upper limit on $e$.

### Counting classes of equivalent encryption keys

Different encryption keys $(N,e)$ and $(N',e')$ can be equivalent; that is encryption with $(N',e')$ (including with random padding, which is necessary to make RSA encryption secure) can always be reversed by using a decryption key $(N,d)$ corresponding to $(N,e)$. This occurs when one of the following holds:

- $N=N'$ and $e\equiv e'\pmod{\lambda(N)}$;
- for degenerate keys $e\equiv1\pmod{\lambda(N)}$, $e'\equiv1\pmod{\lambda(N')}$, and the bitsize of $N$ and $N'$ such that padding remains compatible; with the two common [PKCS#1 paddings](http://www.emc.com/collateral/white-papers/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp.pdf#page=15), that's when $\lceil\log_2(N)/8\rceil=\lceil\log_2(N')/8\rceil$.

We can thus use an alternate definition of *encryption key space* where we assimilate equivalent encryption keys (technically: by considering an element of the set as being an [equivalence class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class) of the equivalence relation among $(N,e)$ pairs that we just defined).

Now, for $k$-bit $N$

- there are $2^{k-2}$ odd $k$-bit integers, thus no more possible $N$;
- for each $N$ we have exactly $\varphi(\lambda(N))$ equivalence classes of encryption keys (where $\varphi$ is the [Euler totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)), thus less than $N/4$.

There are thus less than $3\cdot2^{2k-6}$ equivalence classes of $k$-bit encryption keys, about $2^{2043.6}$. This bound could be slightly improved with a better estimate of $\varphi(\lambda(N))$, and removing those $N$ that are either prime or not [square-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free).

### Conditions commonly added to RSA keys

1. $m=2$ (that is $N$ product of two primes, as in the [original RSA paper](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/Rsapaper.pdf)); this is also mandated by [FIPS 186-4](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=31). In that case, customarily, we note $p=r_1$ and $q=r_2$.
2. $\lceil\log_2N\rceil=k$ for $k$ in some limited set, that is $N$ has an exactly prescribed bit length (because that's good for interoperability); [FIPS 186-4](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=31) mandates $k\in\{1024,2048,3072\}$, with $k=1024$ deprecated.
3. Bounds on individual primes $r_i$, such as $2^{(k-1)/m}<r_i<2^{k/m}$ (this insures condition 2 for any choice of the $r_i$; helps interoperability of private keys in CRT format; and gives protection against some factorization algorithms). [FIPS 186-4](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=31) mandates that.
4. $e\ge e_\text{min}$. Typical values are:

   - $e_\text{min}=3$ (because that's the fastest secure value of $e$ for RSA using good padding); that's mandated by [PKCS#1](http://www.emc.com/collateral/white-papers/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp.pdf#page=6).
   - $e_\text{min}=2^{16}+1$ (because that's less insecure than $e=3$ when insecure padding is used, and other [debatable reasons](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8454/555)); [FIPS 186-4](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=61) mandates that.
5. $e\le e_\text{max}$. Typical values are:

   - $e_\text{max}=e_\text{min}$, which fixes $e$, simplifying things.
   - $e_\text{max}=2^{16}+1$ (this is the most common $e$ around, and I know no reason to use a larger one).
   - $e_\text{max}=2^{2^l}-1$ with $l\in\{5,6,7,8\}$, because that puts an end to using ludicrously large $e$ that waste time, energy, and memory. [FIPS 186-4](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=61) mandates it with $l=8$.
   - $e_\text{max}=N-1$; that's mandated by [PKCS#1](http://www.emc.com/collateral/white-papers/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp.pdf#page=6). Notice that with this definition, there are always equivalent keys.
6. Each $r_i-1$ and each $r_i+1$ is known to have a large prime factor, for some definition of *large*. The rationale is to render some simple factorization algorithms hopeless, and for moderate $\max(\log_2r_i)$ without such requirement it could make sense for an adversary to attempt using these algorithms on each one of a great many $N$, rather than using equivalent effort trying to factor a single $N$ using better algorithms. When $k=1024$, [FIPS 186-4](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=61) mandates this, with *large* defined as $>2^{101}$; when $k=2048$ (resp. $k=3072$) this becomes an optional requirement, and *large* becomes $>2^{141}$ (resp. $>2^{171}$).
7. For $m=2$, it is common to require that $|p-q|>\Delta$. The only benefits are a simple counterargument to someone pretending that Fermat factorization can factor $N$, and catching a few of the many things that can go wrong in an implementation. [FIPS 186-4](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=62) sets $\Delta=2^{k/2-100}$.
8. In addition to condition 6, there might be some upper bound on how large the largest (known) prime factors of $r_i-1$ and $r_i+1$ are. Refer to FIPS [186-4](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=61) which has several options in this regard.
9. In addition to the requirement that each $r_i-1$ has a large prime factor $u$, it has been recommended that $u-1$ has a large prime factor; see [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2303/555).
10. One of many particular key generation algorithm might be specified/used, which will put arbitrary constraints on the $r_i$. For example, algorithm B.3.4 of [FIPS 186-4](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=66) specifies a deterministic algorithm to generate $N$ from a random seed of exactly $security\_strength$ bits, which (by reference to [NIST SP 800-57](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-57/sp800-57-Part1-revised2_Mar08-2007.pdf#page=67)) must be $80$ (resp. $112$, $128$) when $k=1024$ (resp. $2048$, $3072$).

### Evaluating cardinality for a common set of requirements

As example I'll use $m=2$ (cond. 1), $k=1024$ (cond. 2), $a<p<b$ and $a<q<b$ with $a=2^{(k-1)/2}=2^{511.5}$ and $b=2^{k/2}=2^{512}$ (cond. 3), $e=3$ (cond. 4 and 5).

The density of primes near a large $x$ is about $1/\log(x)$, it varies little for $a<x<b$, thus the number of primes in range $]a\dots b[$ is about $t=(b-a)/\log({a+b\over2})\approx2^{501.8}$. Of these, a proportion of about $e-1\over e$ can be used given the requirement $\gcd(e,\lambda(N))=1$. Given that $p\cdot q=q\cdot p$, the cardinality is thus about $(t{e-1\over e})^2/2\approx2^{1001.3}$.

Different key generation requirements can yield vastly different cardinality. For example, the cardinality for 1024-bit RSA with fixed $e$ using algorithm B.3.4 of [FIPS 186-4](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=66) (see req. 10) is *at most* $2^{80}$ (and close to that if the seed can take all possible values).

Comment: Excellent answer, would upvote twice if I could.

Comment: fgrieu, Thank you for taking the time to write this detailed explanation. I now have a much greater understanding of the key space and cardinality of RSA, along with a better understanding of RSA in general.

Comment: Mostly excellent, but in #7 I think you meant m=2 (primes) not k=2 (bits)

Answer (score 3):

A keyspace is the set of all possible keys; it's a set. The cardinality of the keyspace is an integer, and is the number of elements in the keyspace. There is no possibility of confusion, because one is a set and the other is an integer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer cpast. So correct me if i'm wrong, 1024-bit key RSA uses 2 primes each 512 bits. Then the keyspace is the set of primes from 2^511 to 2^512 and the cardinality would be the total number of elements in this set?

Comment: Actually, the keyspace would be the set of prime pairs between $2^{511}$ and $2^{512}$.  Actually, it's somewhat less, because we insist that the product be between $2^{1023}$ and $2^{1024}$.  The set of prime pairs between $2^{511.5}$ and $2^{512}$ is one way to evaluate it.

Comment: To avoid duplicate moduli we want $p<q$, that about halves the cardinality. And then, what about $e$ ? Setting a fixed $e=3$ reduces the cardinality by a factor of about $4/9$. If $e$ is allowed to vary, and we defined an RSA key as $(p\cdot q,e)$, our cardinality increases (and we should account for equivalent $e$ if very large $e$ are allowed). And then, many practical RSA key generation algorithms only generate primes of a certain form (like, such that $p-1$ and $p+1$ each have a known prime factor of a fixed bit size) and that reduces the cardinality of what they could generate.